# XSLT value-of returns text only

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm using XSLT to show a node from XML. This node contains a HTML unordered list like this:

`<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>`

but `<xsl:value-of select="root/node1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` returns only `onetwo`

I know i need to use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` But this does nothing.

I want the output to be the same as in the node, like this:
`<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>`

Comment: What are you selecting in the `select` attribute? What is the output you're wanting from it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use [`<xsl:copy-of>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256183.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:value-of` is used to create text nodes by evaluating the string-value of the selected node.

You need to use `xsl:copy-of`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of

> The `xsl:value-of` element is instantiated **to create a text node**
>   in the result tree. The required `select` attribute is an expression;
>   **this expression is evaluated and the resulting object is converted
>   to a string as if by a call to the [string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-string) function.** The string
>   specifies the string-value of the created text node. If the string is
>   empty, no text node will be created. The created text node will be
>   merged with any adjacent text nodes.
>
> The `xsl:copy-of` element can be used to copy a node-set over to the
>   result tree without converting it to a string. See [[11.3 Using Values
>   of Variables and Parameters with xsl:copy-of](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copy-of)].